# Angular 2 route to new tab

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I have an action where new tab is oneped after click on the button with code like this:

```
this.windowRef.nativeElement.open(
  'my/url, '_blank'
);
```

I have bound this specific route url with a component, so when I go directly to `my/url` I am getting proper page. But when I click on the button new tab is openned, url is changed to `my/url`, but no view specified is shown and after few seconds page is redirected to url and view where clicked button appears.

What is possible reason for such behavior?
How to display component after switching to it's route url and stay with it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retain the scope of your Angular application in another window. Hence calling `$window.open` will open a new window which does not have your original $scope.